# Can you please tell me what this error means?

Tags: vbscript

Can you please tell me why I am getting the following error?

VBScript runtime error: This array is fixed or temporarily locked: 'temp'

This is the code that is generating the error. I am unsure of how to resolve it.

I am just trying to unpack a file that is in DRY folder and move it to ACS folder.
Thank you very much

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Ebooks\DRY\")
For Each fil In fldr.Files
    If LCase( Right( fil.Name, 4 ) ) = ".zip" Then
        zipFilePath = fil.Path
        temp = file.Name
        temp = Left( temp, LEN(temp) - 4 ) ' remove the .zip
        temp = Split( temp, "_" ) ' split base name away from month-day-year
        temp = temp( UBOUND(temp) ) ' get just month-day-year
        temp = Split( temp, "-" ) ' get month day and year separately
        mn = CINT(temp(0)) ' get the month number
        dirName = MonthName(mn,True) & temp(2) ' True means get 3 letter abbrev for month
        Response.Write "Unpacking " & fil.Name & " to directory " & dirName & "<br/>" & vbNewLine
        objZip.UnPack zipFilePath, "D:\ACS\" & dirName & "\"
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by:

```
temp = temp(ubound(temp))
```

and can be fixed by:

```
temp = (temp(ubound(temp)))
```

Comment: That did it!

Thank you very much Alex.

Comment: It forces byval semantics so the locking issue ceases to be a problem as a copy is used, but as you say discreet variables are probably a neater option

Answer (score 1):

While you can assign to/overwrite an array variable with arbitrary values:

```
>> a = Array(1)
>> b = Array(2)
>> a = b
>> b = 4711
>> WScript.Echo Join(a), b
>>
2 4711
```

you can't assign an array element to the variable holding the array itself:

```
>> a = a(0)
>>
Error Number:       10
Error Description:  This array is fixed or temporarily locked
>> a = Array(Array(1), Array(2))
>> a = a(1)
>>
Error Number:       10
Error Description:  This array is fixed or temporarily locked
```

So re/mis-using the temp variable is one cause of your problem. The difference between "fil" and "file" will bite you next.

**After** reading Alex K's answer, I realise that you can avoid that error 10. I **think** that the outer () are 'pass me per value' parentheses, that create a copy ov the original array before the then harmless assignment. But I still believe that using proper variable names and not re-using variables is a better way.

Comment: You guys are the best. I just came back from a meeting and got the exchanges. I would ask for some additional favor extending the functionality of the script below. Right now, it unzips the files and moves the unzipped files. Can it be modified to also move the oroginal zipped file?

And yes, you are right Ekkehard; I got bitten by the file. That was an error and it has been corrected to what it should be = fil. Thanks alot